# Regular Expression Oracle Pl/Sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-substr

I have the following

```
lvc_direccion := 'BL 93 IN 4 AP 401 PABLO VI II SEC';
lvc_Inmueble := REGEXP_SUBSTR (lvc_direccion, '(CONJ|ADL|ALD|ALM|APO|ATR|CAS|CEN|CLJ|CON|ESQ|FCA|TER|URB|VRD|AG|CA|CC|CD|ED|EX|HC|IN|OF|PJ|UN|UR|ZF|C){1}.*? ((TERPLN|SUITE|AGP|ALM|CEL|MLL|PAR|POR|POS|PRJ|SEC|AD|AL|AP|BG|BL|CA|CS|DP|DS|ED|EN|ET|GJ|GS|GT|HG|LC|LM|LT|MD|MJ|MN|MZ|OF|PA|PD|PH|PL|PN|PQ|PS|PT|PW|RP|SA|SC|SD|SL|SS|ST|TO|TZ|ZN|P)|.*)$');
```

I need lvc_Inmueble be equal to 'IN 4 AP', but it shows me 'IN 4 AP 401 PABLO VI II SEC'.

But lvc_direccion can also be 'ED 4F CON Las Flores Cinco' and must be obtained 'CON Las Flores Cinco'.

I have a list of addresses, and from them I need to extract the type of property, the types are (CONJ, ADL, ALD, ALM, APO, ATR, CAS, CEN, CLJ, CON, ESQ, FCA, TER, URB, VRD, AG, CA, CC, CD, ED, EX, HC, IN, OF, PJ, UN, UR, ZF, C), and they usually come in the following form 'Type Name', example 'URB La Tosa' or 'CA 34', the problem is that the substring is within the string 'CRA 30 15 52 URB La Tosa AP 42' or 'CRA 30 15 52 URB La Tosa' or other chains in the same way with different type of property, I use the interior type (TERPLN, SUITE, AGP, ALM, CEL, MLL, PAR, POR, POS, PRJ, SEC, AD, AL, AP, BG, BL, CA, CS, DP, DS, ED, EN, ET, GJ, GS, GT, HG, LC, LM, LT, MD, MJ, MN, MZ, OF, PA, PD, PH, PL, PN, PQ, PS, PT, PW, RP, SA, SC, SD, SL, SS, ST, TO, TZ, ZN, P) for the stop condition, so I extracted 'URB La Tosa AP'. But the problem is that I also need the end of the chain as a stop condition when there is no internal type.

Please i need help with this.
Thanks

Comment: What's the general rule here to extract the string? Can't make out from your examples, could you please explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the end-of-string `$` as one of the type name suffixes to your regular expression:

```
DECLARE
  lvc_direccion varchar2(200) := 'BL 93 IN 4 AP 401 PABLO VI II SEC';
  lvc_Inmueble  varchar2(2000);
  p_prefixes    VARCHAR2(500) := 'CONJ|ADL|ALD|ALM|APO|ATR|CAS|CEN|CLJ|CON|ESQ|FCA|TER|URB|VRD|AG|CA|CC|CD|ED|EX|HC|IN|OF|PJ|UN|UR|ZF|C';
  p_suffixes    VARCHAR2(500) := 'TERPLN|SUITE|AGP|ALM|CEL|MLL|PAR|POR|POS|PRJ|SEC|AD|AL|AP|BG|BL|CA|CS|DP|DS|ED|EN|ET|GJ|GS|GT|HG|LC|LM|LT|MD|MJ|MN|MZ|OF|PA|PD|PH|PL|PN|PQ|PS|PT|PW|RP|SA|SC|SD|SL|SS|ST|TO|TZ|ZN|P';
  p_regexp      VARCHAR2(1100) := '(' || p_prefixes || ').*?(' || p_suffixes || '|$)';
BEGIN
  lvc_Inmueble  := REGEXP_SUBSTR( lvc_direccion, p_regexp );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( lvc_Inmueble );
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
lvc_direccion varchar2(200);
lvc_Inmueble  varchar2(2000);
begin
lvc_direccion := 'BL 93 IN 4 AP 401 PABLO VI II SEC';
lvc_Inmueble := REGEXP_SUBSTR (lvc_direccion, '(CONJ|ADL|ALD|ALM|APO|ATR|CAS|CEN|CLJ|CON|ESQ|FCA|TER|URB|VRD|AG|CA|CC|CD|ED|EX|HC|IN|OF|PJ|UN|UR|ZF|C){1}.*?((TERPLN|SUITE|AGP|ALM|CEL|MLL|PAR|POR|POS|PRJ|SEC|AD|AL|AP|BG|BL|CA|CS|DP|DS|ED|EN|ET|GJ|GS|GT|HG|LC|LM|LT|MD|MJ|MN|MZ|OF|PA|PD|PH|PL|PN|PQ|PS|PT|PW|RP|SA|SC|SD|SL|SS|ST|TO|TZ|ZN|P))');


dbms_output.put_line( lvc_Inmueble);
end;
```

OUTPUT: IN 4 AP

End of the line char is unnecessary

Comment: It works for 'BL 93 IN 4 AP 401 PABLO VI II SEC', but not when the string is 'ED 4F CON Las Flores Cinco', 'ED 4F CON Las Flores Cinco', -> 'CON Las Flores'

Comment: Milton, you'd better re-read what Kaushik has said in his comment under your question. It is unclear which rules to implement in order to get the result out of source data. Also, a few more examples would help. Only one is far from enough.